# GetScript in success ajax just loaded once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a bootstrap modal that I manipulated to running an ajax jQUery when a modal is shown.

```
$urlLocation = 'app/search';
$urlLocationJs = 'app/assets' . '/js/x3dom.js';
$urlLocationJs2 = 'app/assets' . '/js/scene3d.jquery.js';

$("#modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  var form = $('#dynamic-form');
  $.ajax({
    url  : '$urlLocation',
    type : 'post',
    data : form.serialize(),
    success : function(response){
      $.when(
        $.getScript( '$urlLocationJs' ),
        $.getScript( '$urlLocationJs2' ),
        $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
          $( deferred.resolve );
        });
      ).done(function(){
        var myCanvas;
        myCanvas = $('#3dcanvas').scene3d({
          width: "600px",
          height: "400px",
          ViewpointPosition : '3.5 -1 15',
        });
        myCanvas.addLine({x1:-5,x2:13,color:'#ff0000'});
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The case is, when modal is loaded (shown) in first time, the JavaScript that called by

```
$.when(
  $.getScript( '$urlLocationJs' ),
  $.getScript( '$urlLocationJs2' ),
  $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
    $( deferred.resolve );
  })
).done(function(){});
```

is successfully loaded.
But not for second show , third or continously the script is not loaded again.

Please advise.

Comment: did u load it in DOM ready?

Comment: of course Se0ng17 in $(function() { });

Comment: any error in console? if not, is the data value pass always the same? if yes, you need set the cache to false

Comment: no error in console. how to make it chace to false ?

Comment: set `cache: false` or set a random number like timestamp in ur data